# JSP Ajax successful redirection to another JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Pretty much new to JSPs.
I have the following code in my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm()" >
UserName: <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<br />
Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />


</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateLoginForm() {
    var url = "action_form_process.jsp";
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = {  "username":username,
                    "password":password
                };
    http.open("POST", url, false);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    http.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    return true;
}
</script>
```

And there is another JSP 'action_form_process.jsp`.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Form Processing</h1>

<p><b>Welcome User: Coder</b>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

But redirection does not happen. 
No error at all. All the JSPs are in same folder.

Please help and explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why you want to do it using AJAX?

Comment: There are many concerns in my real time application. This is just a snippet that I am trying. I have to achieve it using AJAX only

Comment: Ok but i can't see the code where you are redirecting

Comment: You should be putting the code into a servlet where the `POST` can be processed.  Not sure but I am guessing that a JSP page is being a `GET` by default.

Comment: @soorapadman I duly acknowledge this. Actually I am not pretty sure how to do the same. I have mentioned the another jsp name as url, should it redirect to that jsp automatically or do I have to do something else too?

Comment: Look like proper header information should send along with the request.Since you are sending through POST

Comment: Why not just do a form submit?